# Making group of columns inside table equal sized

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 8 columns inside, I know, that 3 last columns will always be 32 pixel wide, as they contain always the same content. I need to make rest 5 columns equally sized and fill the rest of the space left by fixed td's.

I have following css:

```
.myTable{
width:100%;
border-color:black;
border-width:1px;
}

.fixedTd{
width:32px;
}
```

and my markup:

```
<table class="myTable">
<tr>
<td>Some short content</td>
<td>Some slightly longer content inside</td>
<td>Some very very loooooooong content to show, that columns are not equally sized</td>
<td>Not so long content</td>
<td>Tiny content</td>
<td class="fixedTd"></td>
<td class="fixedTd"></td>
<td class="fixedTd"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've tried adding `table-layout:fixed;` to table class, but in this case `fixedTd` does not override the style - all the tds become equal width.

[image: Issue]

Any ideas how to achieve the result I expect?

Comment: Is the total width of the table fixed? Is so then this is possible, if not, you're trying to combine fixed widths with fluid widths which can be difficult.

Comment: They are already equally sized as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NLpf9/) I just added a border and height to show the difference. So what exactly is your issue?

Comment: what do you mean by `equally sized` 5 columns to have the same width IN TOTAL as the other 3 or each of the 5 columns the same size as each of the 3?

Comment: Nathan Lee - try to add some different length content to the first 5 columns and you will see, that they're NOT equal width.

Comment: DrCopyPaste I mean, that space left in table (3 columns of 32px took some), should be distributed between the 5 columns equally.

Comment: @insomnium_ - using table-layout:fixed seems to work by me. Check the fiddle in my answer - is that what you need or is there still an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current markup... adding `table-layout:fixed;` works

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/X9BBx/2/)**

```
.myTable{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
td
{
    height: 30px;
    background: pink;
}
.fixedTd{
    width:32px;
}
```

Comment: Strange, it works in JSFiddle, but does not in my application. I've updated my question with screenshot.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to assign fixedTd class to my <th> elements within the table, they were ruining all the markup.